# A person that is "storm in a cup of tea" or overestimating personal abilities and skills

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

Do you have any suggestions for a phrase expressing a person that is "storm in a cup of tea" or highly overestimating personal abilities and skills? A phrase that is used in a derogatory fashion usually?

Examples that come to my mind:

> "My startup idea will be evaluated to billions of dollars" he said. But he is
> just <storm in a cup of tea?> since he has no management or technical
> skills.

> He estimated he could fix the electric system of the house since there
> were how-to videos in the Internet.

**Edit:** "Storm in a cup of tea" is a translation from other language where it means a person who talks a lot but has no abilities to achieve the goals.

Comment: I think "storm in a cup of tea" probably means something quite different from what you think it does. Have you looked up the meaning of the phrase?

Comment: The idiom is "storm in a teacup", there's no mention of it having to contain tea.

Comment: A storm in a teacup  is a small or insignificant event that is over-reacted to, as if it were of considerably more consequence.  (phrases.co.uk).  It isn't used to describe a person!  There are lots of variants from "tempest in a teapot", to "raising billows in ladle".

Comment: @Joachim it's translated. That's the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, "storm in a teacup" (or what I am more used to "tempest in a teapot") don't say anything about overestimating ability.

One simple answer to your actual question,however, is "he is all talk".

An example use:
"He says his startup is worth billions, but really he is all talk."